# A grammar is not LL(1) even though it has no left recursion or common prefixes

Tags: compiler-construction, grammar

Supposedly, following grammar is not LL(1). However I cannot find a reason for that. I think it is perfectly LL(1) because it has no left recursion and there is no common prefix issue. Can someone clarify?

[image: http://awesomescreenshot.com/0ae48mn37b]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LL(1) means that a parser can be constructed that uses a single token look-ahead, and in `stmt`, both `assignment` and `subr_call` start with `ID` so a parser cannot distinguish between the two cases just by looking at the first token (`ID`).

Comment: `LL(1)` a simplest language = left lookahead of 1 token.. And indeed for stmt looking at ID does not discriminate between assignment or subr_call. `stmt -> ID ( rest_assignment | rest_subr_call)`would be `LL(1)`.

Comment: @JoopEggen: and `expr`? Or were you just providing one example?

Comment: @rici yes expr has the same problem: primary to ID and subr_call to ID.

Answer (score 0):

From Stanford Notes

> Informally, an LL(1) has no
>   left-recursive productions and has been left-factored. Note that these are necessary
>   conditions for LL(1) but not sufficient, i.e., there exist grammars with no left-recursion or
>   common prefixes that are not LL(1).

So these are the necessary and not sufficient condition.